# Get database info by Firedac replacement for TIBDatabaseInfo from IBX

Tags: delphi, firedac

i need to migrate **IBX** (Interbase/Firebird) connectivity to Firedac
but how can i get specific vendor info like we got by **TIBDatabaseInfo** component by **Firedac**? 
I am interest of counters BackoutCount, DeleteCount, ExpungeCount ...

how to retrive this info by Firedac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get such information through the `TIBDatabase` object from the `FireDAC.Phys.IBWrapper` unit. For example this way (assuming `FDConnection1` is your connection object connected to an IB database):

```
uses
  FireDAC.Phys.IBWrapper;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IBDatabase: TIBDatabase;
begin
  IBDatabase := TObject(FDConnection1.CliObj) as TIBDatabase;

  Memo1.Lines.Assign(IBDatabase.backout_count);
  Memo2.Lines.Assign(IBDatabase.delete_count);
  Memo3.Lines.Assign(IBDatabase.expunge_count);
end;
```